# likely cause?(drupal imagefield conflicts with my module)

Tags: drupal, imagefield

Imagefield is not working properly and I get this lengthy error -

```
{ "status": true, "data": "\x3cdiv id=\"edit-field-image-0-ahah-wrapper\"\x3e\x3cdiv class=\"form-item\" id=\"edit-field-image-0-upload-wrapper\"\x3e\n \x3cdiv class=\"filefield-element clear-block\"\x3e\x3cdiv class=\"widget-preview\"\x3e\x3cdiv class=\"imagefield-preview\"\x3e\x3cimg  .............
```

whenever I upload image. After a bit of detective work, I found out that my own module, which is written for creating custom content type, is causing imagefield to fail. Does anyone know what usually trigger this type of error? Your help is much appreciated.

```
Imagefield - 6.x-3.7   
CCK - 6.x-2.8   
Filefield - 6.x-3.7   
drupal 6.x
```

Comment: Your 'error' does not look like an error, but rather like a json response for an AHAH callback. Maybe your custom module triggers a wrong post/submit somewhere...

Comment: You need to do more digging, isolate what code in your module is causing the problem, and if you're still having trouble, post the relevant code.

Comment: @Mark Trapp: I've working on that since I posted the question. I commented out the whole module with the intent of removing each comment symbol to isolate the code causing this problem. Right from the start, with all the codes being commented out, I still get this error! I tested with built in content type - story with system theme- garland. It's kind of strange that if it is because of my module (seems that way because I get this error only when my module is turned on), shouldn't this error be gone when there is no code to execute in my module file?

Comment: If there is no code in your module, what makes you assume it's your module? Edit your question to provide more detail and the rationale for the conclusions you're making.

Comment: I think you miss the part in parenthesis. Because, I get this error only when my module is turned on. If it is turned on, even all the codes are commented out, I still get this error.

Answer (score 1):

Its tough to say unfortunately. I suspect its something to do with AJAX. Try debugging the Javascript using Firebug in Firefox.

Comment: I'm starting to get headache now. I've commented out the whole module file and tested with built-in content type - story with system theme - garland. This error won't go away. I'm baffle as to why I am still getting this error even there is no executable code in my module. If my module is at fault(seems that way cuz no error when I turn off my module), doesn't it suppose to go away after I commented out all the code in module?

Comment: You probably want to make sure you have latest version of imagefield, cck etc. Also some modules interfere with others -- maybe you want to start (temporarily) disabling some modules on your system and see if the error goes away. Also make sure that the modules on your system have not had people making changes to the code... inadvertently or deliberately. So many errors can be avoided if the code is just pristine!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how related this is to your json output but if you have a custom ahah callback sometimes there are conflicts between imagefield or any drupal form file. So it was recommended here:
http://drupal.org/node/399676#comment-1438662
To use drupal_to_js instead of drupal_json when printing the callback status and data.

```
// don't call drupal_json()
// print drupal_json(array('status' => TRUE, 'data' => $output));
// send the updated file attachments form...  .
// ahah.js uses an iframe and the header output by drupal_json() causes
// problems in some browsers.
print drupal_to_js ( array ( 'status' => TRUE, 'data' => $output ) );

exit;
```

After days of frustration with form fields not keeping thier values until after the imagefield had been uploaded i also found that the ahah.js iframe behaviour of filefield and imagefield can conflict with other ahah functions sitting on other form fields.
Patching ahah.js by following patch #19 here fixed this for me.

http://drupal.org/node/806500#comment-4004316

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems few days ago. I've used Ubercart module, particularly its product module. There is an imagefield in the product creation form. So I got the same message (JSON output) trying to add picture to product. Important note: such a behavior was observed only in Chrome (I'm on dev-channel of it). Firefox handled form successfully.
I didn't investigate the reasons of such a behavior unfotunately. But I advise you to check your site in different browser(s) too.